# “Telephone” is a required value not working in customer edit form

Tags: magento2, customer, forms, form-validation

In my customer edit form, for telephone phone, required field validation is not working when I leave the `telephone`  field blank.
The required validation works for every field except for the telephone field.

When I save the form without `telephone` field, after the backend call it gives me a notification message `" telephone" is required. Enter and try again.`

[image]

This is code for password field in my form

```
<div class="field telephone required">
<label for="telephone" class="label">
    <span>
        Phone Number 
    </span>
</label>
<div class="control">
    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="" title="Phone Number" class="input-text " sr-only="INPUT" for="INPUT" aria-required="true">
</div>
```

I even checked `eav_attribute` table. It has `is_required=1` for `attribute_code='telephone'`

I don't want notification, it should be like other fields inline validation.

Comment: try adding the `required-entry` class to the input.

Comment: change it to simple require `required="true"`

Comment: @Marius Thanks, looks like the vendor code was faulty, they were adding validation class by using fax  $_validationClass = $block->escapeHtmlAttr(
                $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')
                     ->getAttributeValidationClass('fax')
            );

Comment: Just replaced fax  with telephone and it worked in my overridden file

Comment: @summu Put your findings in an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add **required-entry** class in the input field as:

```
<input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone" value="" title="Phone Number" class="input-text required-entry" sr-only="INPUT" for="INPUT" aria-required="true">
```

Its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the vendor code was faulty,
They were adding `_validationClass` by using getAttributeValidationClass of fax

`vendor/Magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/telephone.phtml`

```
<div class="control">
    <?php
        $_validationClass = $block->escapeHtmlAttr(
            $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')
                 ->getAttributeValidationClass('fax')
        );
    ?>
    <input type="text"
           name="telephone"
           id="telephone"
           value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getTelephone()) ?>"
           title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>"
           class="input-text <?= $_validationClass ?: '' ?>"
    >
</div>
```

As `required-entry` class is missing so,
Just change it to `->getAttributeValidationClass('fax')` to 
`->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone')` and it will work.

Comment: I clearly mentioned, that is_required is 1 for  attribute_code='telephone' and you just reiterate same thing using admin panel, solution was i was missing `required-entry` class,